# Rotated strings

Tags: c, string, substring

Write code to check if `s2` is rotation of `s1` using only one call to `isSubString` (ie. `waterbottle` is a rotation of `erbottlewat`).

I write program for this but i can't able to get the desired output. Please guide me where I am going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int isRotated(char *s1, char *s2);
int isSubstring(char *s1, char *s2);

int isRotated(char *s1, char *s2)
{
        int r;
        char s[100];
        if(strlen(s1) == strlen(s2))
                strcpy(s, s1);
        r = isSubstring(s, s2);
        strcat(s, s1);
        return r;
}

int isSubstring(char *s1, char *s2){
        if(strstr(s1, s2))
                return 1;   
        else    
                return 0;
}

int main(void) {
        char s1[100], s2[100];
        printf("Enter the first String\n");
        scanf("%s", s1);
        printf("Enter the second String\n");
        scanf("%s", s2);

        if(isRotated(s1, s2)==1)
                printf("%s and %s are rotated string\n", s1, s2);
        else
                printf("%s and %s are not rotated string\n", s1, s2);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is `STrings`?????

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "desired output"?  What do you get? An error message?

Comment: If the two strings have different lengtjs, `s` is uninitialised, which means `isSubString` and `strcat` may operate on not properly terminated strings.

Comment: You obviously want to find the rotation by concatenating one string to itself and then find the other in the doubled string. Now compare that strategy with what you have written: You compare first and the concatenate.

Comment: You should also pay attention to your string lengths. Your input strings have at most 99 characters, although you don't enforce that limit. (Yea, I know, 100 characters is good enough for toy problems, but eventually not checking or being aware of buffer limits will bite you.) But that also means that you need space for at most 198 characters plus a terminator for the doubled string.

Answer (score 4):

To check if `s2` is rotation of `s1`, you may want to concentrate two `s1`s, and try finding `s2` in the new string.

It is necessary to check the length of `s1` and `s2`. For example, `s1` is "ABCD", `s2` is "CDA". Then `s` is "AB**CDA**BCD". `strstr(s, s2) == 1`, but obviously, `s2` isn't rotation of `s1`.

Also, I'd want to call `strcmp()` first, because I consider a "ABCD" as rotation of "ABCD" itself. However, this is only a matter of definition.

```
int isRotated(char *s1, char *s2)
{
        char s[199];
        if(strlen(s1) != strlen(s2))
                return 0;
        else if(strcmp(s1, s2) == 0)
                return 1;
        else
                strcpy(s, s1);
        strcat(s, s1);
        return isSubString(s, s2);
}
```

BTW: "substring" is one word, so it might be better changing `isSubString()` to `isSubstring()`

Comment: Note that `strstr()` doesn't return `int`, it returns `char *` to the found substring so your text is a bit confusing.

Comment: I've fixed it now, `isSubString()` will return `1` if `strstr(s, s2) != NULL`

Answer (score 3):

If you do the comparison with `strstr()` you are searching a substring in the rotated string. So what you are doing is to find for example the string s1 `ABCD` in an other string s2 `CDAB`. So in fact s2 has no substring s1 in it and your function `int isSubString(char *s1,char *s2)` will always return `false`.

A simple solution for this would be not to compare s1 with s2 directly. You have to compare s2 to a doubled copy of s1: `CDABCDAC`, there you can see that this string contains a substring `ABCD` and your function will return true.

This would mean for your function:

```
int isRotated(char *s1,char *s2)
{
    char s[200];
    strcpy(s,s1); // Copy content of s1 to s
    strcat(s,s1); // Append s again with the content of s1

    if(strstr(s,s2))
       return 1;
    else
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's better, but it might fail for strings of different lengths. Also, you have implemented `isRotated`, not `isSubString`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, using the concatenate-and-look-for-substring approach:

```
int isRotated(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
  const size_t l1 = strlen(s1);
  const size_t l2 = strlen(s2);
  if(l1 != l2)
    return 0;
  char joined[2 * l1 + 1];
  memcpy(joined, s1, l1);
  memcpy(joined + l1, s1, l1);
  joined[2 * l1] = '\0';
  return strstr(joined, s2) != NULL;
}
```

Basically uses more `const`, variable-length array to handle varying lengths, and `memcpy()` when we know the length we're copying.